# GraphQL: Querying for a list of object which have relationship to another object

Tags: graphql

I have set up my schema on GraphCMS and finding graphQL to be very convenient.

I have a workout object and a workoutCategory object. Those two are linked by a many to many relationship.

I'd like to write a query that allows me to get the list of workout which are part of a certain category.

I'm writing the query as follow:

```
workout(where:{ workoutCategories: { id: "xxxxxxx" } }) {
  id
}
```

graphCMS gives me a syntax error on the workoutCategories which does not make sense to me yet

```
Field workout categories is not defined by type WorkoutWhereUniqueInput
```

What do I need to do to be able to achieve my goal?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to query on 'workouts' (see the 's' at the end) and not on 'workout'...